# Chrome Remote Desktop (beta)

Tags: google-chrome, remote-desktop

Chrome just launched the Chrome Remote Desktop (beta) for linux. The instructions are provided here: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/1649523?hl=en

I don't understand this part:

> Find the correct command to start the desktop by looking in /usr/share/xsessions/ for the desktop entry.
>
> For example, the ubuntu-2d.desktop file has the line:
>   Exec=gnome-session --session=ubuntu-2d
>
> The text after ‘Exec=’ is the command to start the session. It should be passed (using quotes if necessary) as a parameter to the lightdm-session script. In this case, the correct command would be:
>
> exec /usr/sbin/lightdm-session "gnome-session --session=ubuntu-2d"

**Somebody please tell me how to exactly do that. Thanks!**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using the quoted example you create a file in your home directory (`~/.chrome-remote-desktop-session`) and place the single line of text:

```
exec /usr/sbin/lightdm-session "gnome-session --session=ubuntu-2d"
```

The easiest way to do both together is to echo the text into the file as in:

```
echo  exec /usr/sbin/lightdm-session "gnome-session --session=ubuntu-2d" > .chrome-remote-desktop-session
```

The line i use for Lubuntu is

```
exec /usr/bin/lxsession -s Lubuntu -e LXDE
```